# how to make individual CCsprites load faster without using a sprite sheet

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I would like to know if there is a way to make CCSprites load faster without using sprite sheets. The main reason I want to avoid sprite sheets is because my images are very large so using .pvr.ccz sprite sheets more than doubles my resources folder to over 40MB and I haven't even added the sprite sheets for the iPhone5.

Comment: So is this question about 1) loading speed or 2) size of the bundle or 3) memory usage when the app is running ?  If you are using .pvr.ccz, you optimize loading speed and bundle size. You dont need to have multiple sprites per sprite sheet with .pvr.ccz, but you can have one texture file per sprite, just like you would with .png or other graphic formats.

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: The question is about 3). I should have mentioned that the sprites are for a scrolling background. Removing an used batch node and adding it again would affect the smoothness of the scrolling.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: thanks for the article, I learnt a lot from it. But my case is somewhat tricky, which involves switching between backgrounds for endless scrolling. Is there a way Please see the above comment.

Comment: if you repeat the same background images just reposition them. Otherwise you'll have to load the next texture in the background, see cctexturecache addimageasync (or similar) method